# How load template for a VueJS component dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to load the template for a VueJS component dynamically,

I tried this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    
    <default></default>
    <div v-component="{currentView}"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Component, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
//import App from './App.vue'
import VueFormWizard from "vue-form-wizard";

@Component({})
export default class detail extends Vue {}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  window.onload = function() {
    //Create the 'default' component
    Vue.component("default", {
      template: "<div>This should be replaced (and will be in 2 seconds)</div>"
    });

    //Create the parent ViewModel
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: "body",
      data: {
        currentView: "default"
      }
    });

    //Pretend to load the data from the server
    //This would actually be $.get("/url", data, function(){...});
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      //Create the new component using the template we received
      Vue.component("BoardFeed", {
        template:
          '<div>Template returned from server, what I really want</div><br>And directives work too:<div v-repeat="items">{{$value}}</div>',
        data: function() {
          return {
            items: [1, 2, 3]
          };
        }
      });

      //And then change the page to that component
      vm.currentView = "BoardFeed";
    }, 2000);
  };
});
</script>
<style>
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

but I get error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "currentView" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: This is not correct vue.js code. Please refer to the vue.js guide to see examples on how to structure your code.